# Pyramid pattern in Ruby need some code correction

Tags: ruby

```
       * 

      ***

     *****

    ********
```

can any one tell me whats the problem with my code

```
i=1
k=5
j=1
t=1
t=k
i.upto(k) do 
    j.upto(t) do 
        print " "
    end  
    t-=1 

    j.upto(2*i-1) do 
        print "*" 
    end 
    j+=1 
    print "\n" 
    i+=1 
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Minimum modifications that will make your code do what you need:

```
i=1
k=5
t=5

i.upto(k) do
  t.times do
    print ' '
  end

  (2 * i - 1).times do
    print '*'
  end

  print "\n"

  t -= 1
  i += 1
end
```

Answer (score 4):

One character value is not good for others programmers.

`String` can be multiplied by using `*` operator.

`puts` function prints strings with break line.
`puts ""` provides the same result with `print "\n"`

`upto` is not so good, use `times` or `each` for intuitive.

`a += 1` is not cool, keep modifying value should to be minimum.

```
def pyramid(height)
  height.times {|n|
    print ' ' * (height - n)
    puts '*' * (2 * n + 1)
  }
end
pyramid 5
```

Will provides

```
     *
    ***
   *****
  *******
 *********
```